# Movie with prophetic paintings in a house

Tags: story-identification, movie

This movie can't be any later than the 90s. A man discovers that a series of paintings scattered all over an old house show the near future. I'm only half sure that the paintings were made by an old woman.

I remember in particular one scene toward the end, where he enters some room like an attic and finds an additional painting that shows how the story will end. In this scene, the painting was upright on the floor, leaning against the wall, not hanged. It may have been covered with a cloth.

Comment: That sounds really familiar. Do you recall by chance if the main character, after seeing the covered painting, falls down the attic's ladder? I'm trying to remember the story for you... stay tuned!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was thinking of "The Reaper's Image" by Stephen King, found in his anthology Skeleton Crew. Similar setting, but involved a mirror haunted by death. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reaper%27s_Image

Comment: It's eerily reminiscent of Nicolas Cage's movie: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowing_(film)